# Firebase Realtime Database for web

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var apps=document.getElementById("kalam");
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("Users").child("357915070121353");

rootRef.on('child_added', function(snap) { 

    apps=snap.val();
    alert(snap.val());
});
```

first of all I am a beginner!!..

I am trying to get a JSON data stored on firebase and this test alert works well,but instead that alert I want to hold the value of the snap in a variable "apps" to get Json data from it easily..so any help?![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

I wanna know about the child Id that you passed there.

Put a console.log(snap.val())

```
var apps=document.getElementById("kalam");
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("Users").child("357915070121353");
rootRef.on('child_added', function(snap) { 
apps=snap.val();
console.log(snap.val());//try it see what your getting.
});
```